# overflow-y:scroll; or overflow-y:auto; didn't work

Tags: css

I have one problem with `overflow-y:scroll;` and `overflow-y:auto;`

I have created this full screen **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/full/QNoXMp/)** and editor screen **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/QNoXMp?editors=1100)** from codepen.io

In this demo when you change the browser width the column positioning changing. But if you change the browser height the `.ChWrP` scroll didn't work. What i am missing here ? Anyone can help me in this regard ?

```
<div class="ChWrP">
   <!--Left Sidebar STARTED-->
   <div class="app-one">

   </div>
   <!--Left Sidebar FINISHED-->
   <!--Right sidebar STARTED-->
   <div class="app-two">

   </div>
   <!--Right Sidebar FINISHED-->
</div>
```

CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width:1210px) {
   .ChWrP{
      flex-direction: column-reverse; 
      top: 0px;
   height: calc(100% - 0px);
   height: -webkit-calc(100% - 0px);
   height: -moz-calc(100% - 0px);  
   overflow-y:auto;
      overflow:hidden;
   } 
   .ChWrP > div { 
      width: 100%;  
   } 
   .ocTppCT {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 650px;
    max-height: 67px;
    color: #1B7BCF;
}
.txt {
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);  
  border-radius:3px;
  -webkit-border-radius:3px;
  -moz-border-radius:3px;
}
span {
    display:none;
}
   .app-one,  .app-two {
      min-height:500px;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have decalared the `overflow` property, giving it a value of `hidden`, *after* declaring the `overflow-y` property. By the cascading nature of CSS, the `overflow-y` property will be overridden.

To fix this either:

- Remove the `overflow` property completely,
- Move the `overflow` property above the `overflow-y` property, or,
- Change the `overflow` property to `overflow-x`.